# how to convert dataframe from wide to long in r (stacking values from multiple columns)?

Tags: r

I am trying to convert a dataframe from wide to long

Currently, the dataframe is set up as:

| ID | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | xxx | yyy | zzz |
| 2 | xxx | yyy | NA |
| 3 | xxx | yyy | NA |
| 4 | xxx | NA | NA |
| 5 | xxx | yyy | zzz |

I'd like it to look like this:

| ID | Values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | xxx |
| 1 | yyy |
| 1 | zzz |
| 2 | xxx |
| 2 | yyy |
| 3 | xxx |
| 3 | yyy |
| 4 | xxx |
| 5 | xxx |
| 5 | yyy |
| 5 | zzz |

Any advice on how to do this?

I have tried to find code to convert from wide to long or transpose all columns into one, but am having trouble figuring this out. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Leah, you probably need `pivot_longer` from the `tidyr` package. Please check this [cheat sheet](https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/blob/main/tidyr.pdf). And welcome to SO!

Comment: `df %>% pivot_longer(-ID) %>% select(-name) %>% drop_na()`